# Django forms with image fields validation

Tags: image, validation, django-forms

I have simple form with 2 fields: Name, Photo.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = My


class My(models.Model):
    Name = models.models.CharField(max_length=512)
    Photo = models.models.ImageField(upload_to=uploader)
```

I'am trying to validate and save this model. User chooses photo and doesn't enter name. Form does not pass validation. And user has error message. Then he enters name, but doesn't choose photo. And form doesn't validate again. But user has already chose photo.

I found article, where author explained this. But he wrote, that information out of date.
Tnx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs covering validation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/
But it think it would be enough to set blank and null to false according to docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/

UPDATE: blank and null diff coverage: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/

But they come as default `False`... snap...
It means that all the validation has to be done as shown in http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice or in templates.
There is many ways to validate forms. You can use even javascript witch would allow post only when fields are valid.
Best probably would be do the validation according to this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/

UPDATE: It seems that its in some sort near duplicate of [Resubmitting Image in ImageField after Validation Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293960/resubmitting-image-in-imagefield-after-validation-error-in-django)

Comment: tnx JackLeo! But in my case image and name are required.

Comment: @user709694 setting blank and null to false means that they cannot be neather blank or null. Update on the way

Comment: ok. But i didn't understand how this information helps me :( The problem, that user have to choose image twice if he didn't enter name.

Comment: yes then its duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293960/resubmitting-image-in-imagefield-after-validation-error-in-django sorry for the bad news you'll see.

Comment: JackLeo tnx for help. I decide to use javascript validation on the client side and standard django validation on the server side for checking if something is wrong with submitted data.

Comment: There has to be a way to just get the form instance and save the image to the instance, even if rest of phone doesn't validate. I'll see what I can find on this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in order to bind imagefield and filefield data to the form. Without that, those fields won't validate.

```
{% block page_content_body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            **<form enctype="multipart/form-data"** action="{% url 'deal_manager:deals_create' %}?place={{ place.id }}" method="post">
                ...
```